# Why does useState trigger rendering with the same value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

As far as I know and read the official documentation, updates will only be triggered if the value is different.

> The set function that lets you update the state to a different value and trigger a re-render.

However, after my testing in version 18.2, there is a situation that triggers repeated rendering.

[image]

demo: https://playcode.io/1796380

I want to know what his capacity is and whether I need to be concerned about it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well one of the console log happens each time the button `onClick` callback is clicked, and the other is an unintentional side-effect, so there's no correlation really to the React component rendering to the DOM. Move that one into a `useEffect` hook to see/check the rendering behavior.

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

export function App(props) {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(1);

  useEffect(() => {
  console.log(count)
  });

  const clickHandle = () => {
    console.log('handle');
    setCount(1000);
  }
  return (
    <div onClick={clickHandle}>click me</div>
  );
}
```

See [Bailing out of a state update](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#bailing-out-of-a-state-update) from the legacy docs for explanation:

> If you update a State Hook to the same value as the current state,
> React will bail out without rendering the children or firing effects.
> (React uses the [Object.is comparison algorithm](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/is#Description).)
>
> Note that React may still need to render that specific component again
> before bailing out. That shouldn’t be a concern because React won’t
> unnecessarily go “deeper” into the tree. If you’re doing expensive
> calculations while rendering, you can optimize them with **useMemo**.

Basically, if you enqueue a state update that is the same value/reference as the current state it may trigger one additional component rerender, but no more than this and it doesn't render deeper into the ReactTree.